# Access row values through row-based buttons in dynamic table PHP

Tags: php, css, mysql

I am new in PHP+mysql and trying to make a bidding website and created a page that displays the current items for auction and their respective attributes. I have a `bid` and `history` button in each row which is specific to each row-data. How can I retrieve the row data through clicking the row-specific button. I have no primary key in the current table so I'm using `Serial number` as the distinct column for now:

The `bid` and `history` buttons have specific classes associated with them. How can I check these dynamically formed buttons for the click event and retrieve the respective row data?

Code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","users");
$sql = "Select * from bid_items";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$table_str = '<table id="product table"><tr>
<th>Sno</th><th>Owner Name</th><th>Item Name</th><th>Closing date</th><th>Bid amount</th><th>Status</th><th>Bid</th><th>History</th></tr>';
$i=1;
if($result->num_rows>0)
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    if($row["closing_date"]>date("Y-m-d"))
    {
      $table_str .= '<tr>';
      $table_str .= '<td>'.($i++).'</td><td>'.$row["owner_name"].'</td><td>'.$row["item_name"].'</td><td>'.$row["closing_date"].'</td><td>'.$row["bid_amount"].'</td><td>Open</td><td>'.'<input type="submit" class="bids" value="bid">'.'</td><td>'.'<input type="submit" class="hist" value="history">'.'</td>';
      $table_str .= '</tr>';
    }
    else {
      $table_str .= '<tr>';
      $table_str .= '<td>'.($i++).'</td><td>'.$row["owner_name"].'</td><td>'.$row["item_name"].'</td><td>'.$row["closing_date"].'</td><td>'.$row["bid_amount"].'</td><td>Closed</td><td>'.'<input type="submit" class="bids" value="bid" disabled>'.'</td><td>'.'<input type="submit" class="hist" value="history">'.'</td>';
      $table_str .= '</tr>';
    }
  }
}
$table_str.='</table>';
echo $table_str;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Bidding Items</title></head>
<style type="text/css">
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%;
  color: #d96459;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:left;
}
th
{
  background-color:#d96459;
  color:white;
}
tr:nth-child(even)
{
  background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
</style>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Current output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace both

```
<input type="submit" class="bids" value="bid">
<input type="submit" class="hist" value="history">
```

with

```
<a class="bids" href="?bid=<?php echo $row['serial']; ?>">bid</a>
<a class="hist" href="?hist=<?php echo $row['serial']; ?>">history</a>
```

Now each button will contain their respective serial numbers. With GET request you can get the id corresponding to that row and get values from the database.

Add these two before $conn so that when your file loads with the GET request, it'll get the serial at first.

```
if(isset($_GET['bid']) && $_GET['bid'] != '')
{
    $serial = htmlspecialchars($_GET['bid'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $type = "bid";
}

if(isset($_GET['hist']) && $_GET['hist'] != '')
{
    $serial = htmlspecialchars($_GET['hist'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $type = "history";
}
```

Now you can get your individual row values by fetching from database with WHERE serial=$serial.

Let me know if it helped or not or if you were looking for something else.